# Find average time between the first and second listening by users

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Let's say I have the following table of user listenings for a music platform:

| id | user_id | started_at | finished_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 101 | '2017-10-05 08:38:22' | '2017-10-05 13:59:03' |
| 2 | 101 | '2017-10-05 15:15:30' | '2017-10-05 15:15:41' |
| 3 | 101 | '2017-10-05 15:15:46' | '2017-10-05 15:46:46' |
| 4 | **102** | '2017-10-12 13:45:27' | '2017-10-12 15:14:49' |
| 5 | 103 | '2017-10-10 12:21:19' | '2017-10-10 12:42:27' |
| 6 | 103 | '2017-10-10 12:45:56' | '2017-10-10 12:52:22' |
| 7 | 103 | '2017-10-10 14:25:54' | '2017-10-10 16:32:57' |
| 8 | 103 | '2017-10-10 16:35:01' | '2017-10-10 18:09:50' |

where ***id (int)*** is record of user that listened to music (or book or any other material), ***user_id (int)*** is a listener id, ***started_at (timestamp)*** is time when user started listening and ***finished_at*** is when user finished listening

What I need to do is find average time between the first and second listening by user. For example, for a first user with user_id = 101, it will be:

**'2017-10-05 15:15:30' (started_at column, second row) - '2017-10-05 13:59:03' (finished_at, first row)**

Which gives 1 hour and 15 minutes time difference.

For that case I wrote the following code:

```
   SELECT  user_id, (TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, pDataDate, started_at)/3600)
   FROM    (
        SELECT  *,
                LAG(finished_at) OVER (ORDER BY finished_at) pDataDate
        FROM    listenings
    
        ) q
   WHERE   pDataDate IS NOT NULL
```

My problem is in handling the cases in which there is **only one user_id** in the table (user_id = 102 in this example). It has only one row which means *started_at* and *finished_at* at the same column. I don't how to properly write a statement that combines both of the cases. Can someone suggest the query (may be with if/case statements) that covers both of the cases?

Also, I want to find a way to only take the average of the first two top rows of the group. Say, for user_id = 101, I will only take the average between rows 1 and 2.

Thanks in advance and sorry if I couldn't write it clearer. I will probably edit question for convenient reading

Comment: I removed the SQL Server tag because this is clearly MySQL.

Comment: What result do you expect for user_id=102?

Comment: The result for user_id = 102 should be just difference between finished_at and started_at at the same row:  '2017-10-12 15:14:49' - '2017-10-12 13:45:27'

Comment: Why? This has nothing to do with the difference between 1st and 2n trial. Also what is *average* in the title of your question? If you want to average the results of your query it would be wrong to consider cases where there is no 2nd trial.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I will rewrite the title to avoid confusion.
Based on the provided table:
user_id = 101 has three rows. I need to find the average time between the first and second listening by users. So, for this subtract  row 2, started_at value: '2017-10-05 15:15:30' by row1, finished_at value: '2017-10-05 13:59:03.  By this logic  I will have an _N_ number of user listening time. Then, I just need to take the average of only first two number of listening time. For the cases where there is one user_id, I need the just difference between between finished_at and started_at columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `LAG()`, use `ROW_NUMBER()`.  You can then use aggreagtion:

```
SELECT user_id,
        TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, MAX(finished_at), NULLIF(MIN(finished_at), MAX(finished_at))) / 3600
FROM (SELECT l.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORJDER BY finished_at) as seqnum
      FROM listenings l    
     ) l
WHERE seqnum <= 2
GROUP BY user_id;
```

This returns `NULL` if a user has only one row.

Comment: Thanks very much! Is this query takes the average time difference for the first two rows for a certain user_id or something else? Since I am a newbie in SQL, I thought there should be an AVG clause ..

Comment: @Beginn_noo . . . Each user has only one first row and one second row, so no aggregation is needed.  You would need `AVG()` if you wanted the average over *all* users.